# show listview in the second activity

Tags: android

In my first `Activity` I have a list of elements, and every time I clicked on a row in my list, I take two elements from the list and pass the elements of a second activity to Fill A Url.

I analyze the result of JSON in a `ListView` (like a shopping cart) then a button that lets you see the list of the second activity without worrying about the URL, just showing the list of elements.

The problem is when I click on the button to show me the list. My second activity still waiting for the two items to fill the URL and I don't want that.

**My Code**

```
     TextView texto;
            texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
            String text2 = texto.getText().toString();
            Intent intent2= new Intent(busqueda.this,Compra.class);
            intent2.putExtra("TOKENS", datas);
            intent2.putExtra("CODI", text2);
            // startActivity(intent2);
            Toast.makeText(busqueda.this,"Agregado...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return   super.onContextItemSelected(item);
```

**Second Activity**

```
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNombre);
        code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNro);
        prod = new ArrayList<>();
        lista_eligida = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_eligida);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String linked = null;
        String coded = null;
        if (extras != null) {
            linked = extras.getString("TOKENS");
            coded = extras.getString("CODI");
        }

            String url = "http://www.air-intra.com/apps/air-app/agregar.php?token=" + linked + "&codiart=" + coded + "";
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            JSONObject jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            try {


                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(jsonStr));
                String nroComp= jsonObj.getJSONObject("PR").getString("nrocompro");
                String Nomb= jsonObj.getJSONObject("PR").getString("nombre");
                String code= jsonObj.getJSONObject("PR").getString("codigo");
                recode=""+code;
                reNombre=""+Nomb;
                reNumero=""+nroComp;
                Log.e("CODE", recode);

                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PRR");
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String codig = c.getString("codigo");
                    String des = c.getString("descrip");
                    String prec = c.getString("precio");
                    // String garb = c.getString("fisicolug");

                    HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                    contacto.put("codigo", codig);
                    contacto.put("descrip", des);
                    contacto.put("precio", prec);
                    //contact.put("fisicolug", garb);

                    prod.add(contacto);

                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {

            }
        return null;
    }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result){
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            codigo.setText(recode);
            nombre.setText(reNombre);
            numero.setText(reNumero);
            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Compra.this, prod,
                    R.layout.item_carrito, new String[]{"codigo", "descrip", "precio"},
                    new int[]{R.id.tvcode, R.id.tvdescrip, R.id.tvprec});
            lista_eligida.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify this a bit, you have a list on Activity1 and when you tap one an element you want to pass that information to Activity2 and create a URL? Maybe include the relevant code - the `onClick()` for that button.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i want to do , but if i nclude the same code for the buton i gonna stil pass the parameters too... when i click on the button i not supose to read the url
Sorry for my bad english